# Help me find the deadlock

Tags: java, hibernate, deadlock

This is the first time I see this code myself where we are getting deadlock.

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Here is the code: (Java/pseudocode)

```
// This function inside a Job implementation of Quartz Job
execute(...)
{
     UserTransaction trans = getTransaction();
     trans.begin();

     Session session = getSession();

     List<PersistedObject> list = getListOfPersistedObjects(...)

     int counter = 0;
     loop(l : list)
     {
           counter++;

          // this is just sending a message using information based on the object
           sendMessage(l); 

           // Create a 2nd "archive" object based on the data inside the l object
           PersistedObjectArchive archive = new PersistedObjectArchive(l)

           session.save(archive);
           session.flush();

           session.delete(l);
           session.flush();

           if(counter % JDBC_BATCH_SIZE_CONSTANT_FROM_SOMEWHERE == 0)
           {
                session.flush(); // Deadlock Exception happens here
                session.clear();
           }
     }

     trans.commit();
}
```

I think the code above can be cleaned up a bit - I dont see the use of so many flushes, but I am just going with the existing code right now.

Anyone notice what can be causing the deadlock?

Comment: Not enough info to find a deadlock....  What's inside all the functions used by the session object?

Comment: Are there other transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a deadlock in the database, it is a timeout when waiting for a lock held by another database session. You should turn on SQL logging in Hibernate and see what exactly your application is doing right before the exception is thrown. You can also use Oracle's dynamic performance views to get more information from the database. For example, select from V$LOCK to find currently held locks; you probably needs to join this to V$SESSION to find out more about the lock holder.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the exception I think the problem is not in this code, I think it is a time out from the database.

BTW: you should rethink the way you handle transactions. I think a `try{...}finally{trans.rollback);}` could help in some situations.